# Why does using iterator() gives me error, I have also imported package?

Tags: java

```
Iterator itr=m1.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
            if(m2.containsKey(m.getKey())){
                System.out.println(m2.containsKey(m.getKey()));
            }
    }
```

```java
Solution.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        Iterator itr=m1.iterator();
                       ^
  symbol:   method iterator()
  location: variable m1 of type Map<Character,Integer>
1 error
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `Map` doesn't have an `Iterator`, it does have an `entrySet()` (and that has an `iterator()`). Like,

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> iter = m1.entrySet().iterator();
```

Comment: @Sahil, also, I'd recommend you to iterate over entry-set, which is `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`

Answer (score 0):

`Iterator itr=m1.iterator();` should be this:

`Iterator iter = m1.entrySet().iterator()`